# AngularJS NgDisabled without using Fieldset

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation for my CSS, and it uses `fieldset` for [form style](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html). I cannot therefore use it on my form to disable my form under certain conditions without pretty much overwrite all the CSS of it (which I actually use in my form for other reasons!)

I tried to apply `ng-disabled` to the `form`, `div` or something else, but nothing worked! What are my options?

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. `ng-disabled` just sets/removes the `disabled` property, so it will only have any effect on HTML elements that "understand" disabled (e.g. buttons, inputs etc).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Normally you apply it to `fieldset` but because of the styling of Foundation, I cannot use it. I could also apply it to each input/button manually. I wanted to know if there was another tag that I could use other than `fieldset` to wrap my entire form in.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why you can't apply it to fieldset or how Foundation prevents you (I am not familiar with Foundation).

Comment: No no, I CAN apply it to the `fieldset`. BUT the Foundation's `fieldset` has some predefined CSS that makes it not appealing for all fields to be used. So it is not that I can't use it, it is that  I don't want to

Comment: Now I understand :) I don't think there is much you can do, because the appearance of the contents of a disabled fieldset probably depends on their having a disabled fieldset parent. If you remove the fieldset, then the appearance of disabled elements might not appeal to you.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try! Thanks for the tips! If you provide an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that the appearance of the contents of a disabled fieldset (e.g. inputs, buttons etc) depends on their having a disabled fieldset parent. If you remove or replace the fieldset, then the appearance (and behaviour) of your controls won't be very useful (or appealing).